# Can't define tense in a sentence

Tags: tense

"I’d been driving home late that night."

What hides under "I'd"? If it is "I had", then it seems Past Perfect Continuous tense suits best here, but Past Perfect Continuous supposed to have two actions, isn't it? So, I'm confused, please help me with clarification

Comment: It is "had". Sounds like there are more sentences to follow though.

Comment: @Peter So, one tense could cover two sentences?

Comment: When you say 'supposed to have two actions', do you mean something like _I'd been driving home late when I'd heard the news on the car radio_?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I mean these kind of actions. In my case it says: "I’d been driving home late that night. As I came up to my house, my headlights landed on the biggest deer I had ever seen, right in the middle of the road." Is it Past Perfect Continuous?

Comment: This sentence sounds odd on its own for that reason, but the “other action” could be in the next sentence. Context matters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shortened word is indeed "had". "Would" is also abbreviated this way, but makes no sense here.

The past perfect continuous tense refers to something that continued (in this case driving) before something else in the past. Nothing else is specifically mentioned, so the later time is the time that the sentence is set.

Because narratives are usually in past tense, and there is no specific later time mentioned in the sentence, your sentence sounds much like a sentence from a narrative, as I implied in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's "had", as you suspect, and this is indeed the past perfect continuous (or "past perfect progressive") tense. I'm not sure what you mean by "two actions".  There are already two verbs here: "been" (past participle of "be") and "driving" (present participle of "drive").  It doesn't require another one.